# Load to 16bit register, least significant bit in first or second register?

Tags: assembly, endianness, machine-code, z80

I am programming in Z80 assembly; I'm confused about endianness.

Regarding the following instruction:

```
LD HL,d16
```

Will the bytes `21 FF DF` result in `H = FF` and `L = DF` or `H = DF` and `L = FF`?

Comment: It results in L=FF, H=DF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Z80 datasheet](http://www.z80.info/zip/z80cpu_um.pdf), p.54 (page #74 in the PDF):

> In all extended immediate or extended addressing modes, the low order 
>   byte always appears first after the Op Code.

So when the instruction opcode is `21 FF DF`, LSB = FF.